# What does the tick mark in software sources list > other sources tab > tick box besides each ppa link do?

Tags: update-manager

I want to know whether I should tick the box besides vs code binary.

[Software sources list other software tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogarw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To disable a repository temporarily, untick the checkbox next to its name.

(via [Official Ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu))

Comment: I have it unticked for microsoft ppa yet I am getting updates for VS code. I didn't untick it. I can't even tick it without opening the software-properties-gtk with sudo so I am pretty sure it wasn't me who unticked it but I have still been recieving VS code updates.